# ng-repeat - detecting if image exists and handling

Tags: angularjs

I am displaying some images in my view using:

```
<div class="post" ng-repeat="post in vm.posts">
  <a href="{{post.url}}" target="_blank">
    <img ng-src="/feed/{{post.image}}.jpg" />
  </a>
</div>
```

but the `vm.posts.image` will be empty on occasions. At the moment the icon for an incorrect image src is displaying in the browser when the value is empty but I would just prefer to show a black space.

**Update:**
I've managed to make it work using `ng-if` (shown below) - is there a way to do this within the ng-src tag?

```
<div ng-if="post.image">

</div>
```

Comment: Your problem here is that whenever the post.image is empty, ng-src looks for /feed/.jpg path and thats the reason why it shows a broken image. Either follow the answer below, or change your image path and remove /feed/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to show the blank space when the posts doesn't have image details, if this is the case then u can use `ng-if` which removes the element from the dom if its not present . ng/show/ng-hide could also be used but there is difference between using them vs ng-if . it depends on your requirement.

```
<img ng-if="post.image" ng-src="/feed/{{post.image}}.jpg" />
```

As per the updated question , condition can be use for ng-src as below. if the post.image is false value then ng-src would be empty as below

```
<img  ng-src="{{ post.image?('/feed/'+ post.image +'.jpg'):'' "}}/>
```

Comment: @tommyd456 as per your updated question added the answer , hope this is what u required !